# Regular Expression that matches number with max 2 decimal places

Tags: java, android, regex, numbers

I'm writing a simple code in java/android.

I want to create regex that matches:

```
0
123
123,1
123,44
```

and slice everything after second digit after comma.

My first idea is to do something like that:

```
^\d+(?(?=\,{1}$)|\,\d{1,2})

 ^ - from begin
 \d+ match all digits
 ?=\,{1}$ and if you get comma at the end
 do nothin
 else grab two more digits after comma
```

but it doesn't match numbers without comma; and I don't understand what is wrong with the regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use

```
^(\d+(?:,\d{1,2})?).*
```

and replace with `$1`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/d5YTWC/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
  -`(\d+(?:,\d{1,2})?)` - Capturing group 1 matching:

  - `\d+`  - one or more digits
  - `(?:,\d{1,2})?`  - an optional sequence of:

    - `,` - a comma
    - `\d{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits
- `.*` - the rest of the line that is matched and not captured, and thus will be removed.

Comment: FYI: Do not forget to double the backslashes in Java/Android string literals

Comment: Thans man it let me get rid of a lot of if-else statements in my code that looks very ugly :)

Answer (score 4):

basic regex : `[0-9]+[, ]*[0-9]+`

In case you want to specify min max length use:

`[0-9]{1,3}[, ]*[0-9]{0,2}`

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
,{1}
```

says: exactly ONE ","

Try:

```
,{0,1}
```

for example.